# pasar varios arrays de php a javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

el siguiente código php que genera dos arrays

```
<?php
    //los datos salen de una tabla mysql
    $last_year_sales = [2589, 2589, 1478, 2587, 7852, 9632];    
    $current_year_sales = [1250, 1480, 1156, 3589, 7521, 9632];

    //enviar
    echo json_encode($last_year_sales);
    echo json_encode($current_year_sales);
?>
```

Necesito recibirlos en otra pagina y lo hago asi

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var last_year = JSON.parse(this.last_year_sales);
       var current_year = JSON.parse(this.current_year_sales);
    }
```

Llega esto

```
[2589, 2589, 1478, 2587, 7852, 9632][1250, 1480, 1156, 3589, 7521, 9632]
```

Como hago el requerimiento de los dos array? o como lo hago con ajax?

Gracias.

Comment: En el php, unifica el resultado dentro de un array `$result = ['last_year_sales' => $last_year_sales, 'current_year_sales' => $current_year_sales]; echo json_encode($result);` Después accedes desde javascript por cada una de sus _key's_, _last_year_sales_ o _current_year_sales_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede resolver de varias maneras te paso un ejemplo, utilizando tu contexto.

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
</html>

<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    datatype: 'text'
    }).done(function (response) 
    {
        resultado = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(resultado["last_year_sales"]);
        console.log(resultado["current_year_sales"]);
    });
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $last_year_sales = [2589, 2589, 1478, 2587, 7852, 9632];    
        $current_year_sales = [1250, 1480, 1156, 3589, 7521, 9632];
        $respuesta["last_year_sales"] = $last_year_sales;
        $respuesta["current_year_sales"] = $current_year_sales;
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
?>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Metelos en un arreglo asociativo de PHP

```
<?php
    $arr = array();

    //los datos salen de una tabla mysql
    $last_year_sales = [2589, 2589, 1478, 2587, 7852, 9632];    
    $current_year_sales = [1250, 1480, 1156, 3589, 7521, 9632];

    $arr['last_year_sales'] = $last_year_sales;
    $arr['current_year_sales'] = $current_year_sales;
    //enviar
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

En JS los vas a cachar así como lo haces

```
   var last_year = JSON.parse(this.last_year_sales);
   var current_year = JSON.parse(this.current_year_sales);
```

Comment: la parte del php esta bien, gracias, pero creo que no lo estoy leyendo de la forma correcta por que no he podido recuperar los array...